# Select data from specific time frame in mysql and return in php form

Tags: php, sql-server

Currently, I have a set of data and I wanted to generate a report out of it. But my report requires the time from the current(today) 6 pm until 2 am (the next day). The normal query will only select the data until 12 am only. This is the coding I have try but is not working. May I know how to select it correctly? (Assume 26th oct is the current date and 27th oct is the next day, therefore, we only need to select data from 26th oct 2018 18:00:00 until 27th oct 2018 02:00:00)

Here is my database.

[image]

and here is my what my outcome wanted.

[image]

here is my coding:

```
<div class="table-responsive" ><!-- table-responsive Starts -->
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ><!-- table table-bordered table-hover Starts -->
                    <thead><!-- thead Starts -->

                        <tr>
                            <th>No:</th>
                            <th>Transaction No:</th>
                            <th>User ID:</th>
                            <th>Metallic Point (Debit):</th>
                            <th>Metallic Point (Credit):</th>
                            <th>DateTime:</th>

                        </tr>

                    </thead><!-- thead Ends -->
                    <tbody>


                            <?php
                            include_once '../tmkdashboard/includes/db.php';

                                $get_member = "SELECT * 
                                    FROM transaction_record_tpg
                                    WHERE collect_outlet = 'TMA' 
                                    AND timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110))
                                    AND timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR,2,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,110)) ";


                                $run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$get_member);

                                $i = 0;

                                while($row_orders = mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer)){

                                $id = $row_orders['trans_id'];

                                $user = $row_orders['user_id'];

                                $debit = $row_orders['m_debit'];

                                $credit = $row_orders['m_credit'];

                                $date = $row_orders['collected_datetime'];

                                $i++;
                            ?>
                        <tr><!-- tr Starts -->

                            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $user; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $debit; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>


                        </tr><!-- tr Ends -->
                            <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, since your SQL version is clearly SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of your query which should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction_record_tpg
WHERE
    collect_outlet = 'TMA' AND
    timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, 18, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE())) AND  -- 6pm today
                      DATEADD(HOUR, 26, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()));     -- 2am tomorrow
```

This answer works by adding either 18 hours (for 6pm) or 26 hours (for 2am) to the current date at midnight.

Comment: But it show mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\Application\Apps\xampp\htdocs\tmkdashboard\report.php, so what should i change in this part in order to return the data?

Comment: @louis Your question seemed to focus on the SQL part of your code.  I didn't check your script for other problems, and my forte is not PHP programming.  If you have major other PHP problems, that might work as another question later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try.

```
$start_time = date("Y-m-d 18:00:00");
$end_time = date("Y-m-d 02:00:00", strtotime("1 day"));
$get_member = "SELECT * 
           FROM transaction_record_tpg
           WHERE collect_outlet = 'TMA' 
           AND timestamp >= '{$start_time}'
           AND timestamp <= '{$end_time}' ";  
$run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$get_member);
// add check error
if (!$run_customer) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: hi, I had tried your method but the ( mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in) warning keep show up

Comment: you can check it